# How do I use Chrome webrequest API on an extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

Alright, Im fairly new to making chrome extensions in general and I want to know how to intercept a  tag and make a site run a different javascript file when the script is called. I have an extension made to test this out and try to figure it out myself, but it has not worked. When I type in the url of the file to replace, it redirects me to the file that I want it to, but the  tag won't redirect to it or if it is, it's not running any of the code from the file. Please help?

**content.js**

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
function(details) {
    if( details.url == "http://www.bellum.io/js/attackCooldown.js" )
        return {redirectUrl: "http://yourjavascript.com/1177311921/alertjs.js" };
},
{urls: ["*://www.bellum.io/*.js"]},
["blocking"]);
```

**manifest.json**

```html
{
  "name": "Simple Webrequest Test",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Webrequest Test",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>","webRequest","webRequestBlocking","http://*/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["content.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }
}
```

Comment: The URL is probably different on that tag. Like `https` scheme or something added after `.js`

Comment: @wOxxOm The full script tag is this: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/attackCooldown.js"></script> So, what exactly is the issue?

Comment: Check the real URL in devtools network panel.

Comment: Without more information we are reduced to **guessing** what the problem is. Please provide a *complete*, but minimal, [mcve]. This needs to include the HTML against which this is running, or the website on which it is running which is causing the issue. Ideally, all information needs to be *in the question*, including the HTML against which you are running which produces the problem.